# How to build logic to find the history of Red and Amber records with below example

Tags: sql, hive, logic

```
with archer_summary_base as (select * from kri.archer_kri_latest_summary 
where segment='All Segments'  and  Level_I_Risk!='' and metric_identifier in ('Mandatory') and  (metric_results_status='Amber' or metric_results_status='Red' or metric_results_status is null) and
(month='January' or month='February' or month='March' or month='December' or month='November' or  month='April'  or month is null) AND (year=2021 or year=2020 or year is null) 
and status='Active' and originated_source ='Archer'),
--select * from archer_summary_base
archer_summary_main as (select * from kri.archer_kri_latest_summary where metric_id in (select  metric_id from archer_summary_base)
and (month='January' or month='February' or month='March' or month='December' or month='November' or  month='April'  or month is null)
AND (year=2021 or year=2020 or year is null)  and segment='All Segments' and Level_I_Risk !='' and  originated_source ='Archer' and
metric_identifier in ('Mandatory')),
breach_kri_report AS (select metric_id,
trim(Level_I_Risk) as Level_I_Risk,
trim(Metric_Name) as Metric_Name,
(case when format in ('Percentage') then concat(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(Green_threshold_min,'\\.0+$',''),'(\\d+\\.\\d+?)0+$','$1'),'%','-',regexp_replace(regexp_replace(Green_threshold_max,'\\.0+$',''),'(\\d+\\.\\d+?)0+$','$1'),'%')
when format in ('Monetary Amount') then concat('$',format_number(cast(Green_threshold_min as bigint),0),' -','$',format_number(cast(Green_threshold_max as bigint),0))
when format in ('Number') then concat(cast(Green_threshold_min as bigint),'-',cast(Green_threshold_max as bigint)) 
end) as Green_Threshold,
trim(PATH_TO_GREEN_INDICATOR) as P2G_Indicator,
concat(substring(Month,1,3), '-', substring(year,3,4)) as Month_Name,
(case when format in ('Percentage') then concat(cast(metric_value as bigint),'%')
when format in ('Monetary Amount') then  concat('$',(format_number(cast(metric_value as bigint),0)))
when format in ('Number') then format_number(cast(metric_value as bigint),0) end) as DerivedValue_Avg
from archer_summary_main group by metric_id,Level_I_Risk,Metric_Name,Green_threshold_min,Green_threshold_max,PATH_TO_GREEN_INDICATOR,month,year,format,metric_value),
--Select * from breach_kri_report,
exsummary as (SELECT b.Level_I_Risk,
b.Metric_Name,
b.Green_Threshold,
b.P2G_Indicator,
case when Month_Name='Nov-20' then DerivedValue_Avg  end as Nov_20,
case when Month_Name='Dec-20' then DerivedValue_Avg  end as Dec_20,
case when Month_Name='Jan-21' then DerivedValue_Avg  end as Jan_21,
case when Month_Name='Feb-21' then DerivedValue_Avg  end as Feb_21,
case when Month_Name='Mar-21' then DerivedValue_Avg  end as Mar_21,
case when Month_Name='Apr-21' then DerivedValue_Avg  end as Apr_21
FROM breach_kri_report b)
select  
t.Level_I_Risk,
t.Metric_Name,
t.Green_Threshold,
t.P2G_Indicator,
collect_list(Nov_20)[0] as Nov_20,
collect_list(Dec_20)[0] as Dec_20,
collect_list(Jan_21)[0] as Jan_21,
collect_list(Feb_21)[0] as Feb_21,
collect_list(Mar_21)[0] as Mar_21,
collect_list(Apr_21)[0] as Apr_21
from exsummary t
group by t.Level_I_Risk, t.Metric_Name, t.Green_Threshold, t.P2G_Indicator
```

Below results i am getting shown in screen shot

[image]

the 'Green' which are circled should not come when I run the query because I want to get history for Red and amber. I am ok to get the green records as part of the history but not in the beginning or in the latest months

Below is what I am trying to achieve

[image]

Comment: what's in table_A? also the query you included seems to be incomplete

Comment: @umberto-petrov I have put the complete query

Answer (score 0):

Here is an outline to a possible query:

Issue a subquery using a window function, partition by year and month, pick the lowest pk_key by sorting by year, month and pk_key ascending and select the first result for each partition.
Then use the results in combination with a `where` clause and a second constraint:

`... where not(pk_key in (first_query.pk_key) and metric_results_status = 'GREEN')`

Sorry, but I can't provide anything more specific, since the details you gave are not very clear on as to what your database structure in actuality looks like.

May God have mercy upon your soul!